# Remove duplicates from a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to now how to remove duplicates from a multi-dimensional array. I have an array which looks like this:

**Array before**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Hello'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Friend'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Hello'
        [1] => 'Code'
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Hello'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'hello'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Hello'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )
)
```

And i want it to look like this:

**Array after**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Hello'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Friend'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'Hello'
        [1] => 'Code'
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 'hello'
        [1] => 'Test'
    )
)
```

As you see, the third and fith element got removed because element zero is identical with them. What is the most efectiv way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

[Php output demo](https://3v4l.org/Gm9B3)

```
$arrays = [
    [
        "Hello",
        "Test"
    ],
    [
        "Friend",
        "Test"
    ],
    [
        "Hello",
        "Test"
    ],
    [
        "hello",
        "Test"
    ]
];

var_dump(array_unique($arrays, SORT_REGULAR));
```

That would give you:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Test"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Friend"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Test"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "hello"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
$myArray = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

You can try it here:

https://repl.it/repls/TrueToughRotation

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. No intermediate variables are saved.

We used this to de-duplicate results from a variety of overlapping queries.

```
$input = array_map("unserialize",array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```